# How selectRow of PickerView can affect on Button enabled?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have UIPickerView and button. I want if I choose raw number 0 then button is not enabled and vice versa. I have this construction in my code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    ...
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPicker: UIPickerView!

    let firstData = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"]
    let secondData = ["00", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]

    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!

    var first: Int!
    var second: Int!

    var firstRaw = 1
    var secondRaw = 0
            ...
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.firstPicker.delegate = self
            self.firstPicker.dataSource = self
            self.secondPicker.delegate = self
            self.secondPicker.dataSource = self

            firstPicker.selectRow(firstRaw, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            secondPicker.selectRow(firstRaw, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            if (self.firstRaw == 0) && (self.secondRaw == 0) {
                self.buttonOutlet.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                self.buttonOutlet.isEnabled = true
            }
        ...
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if pickerView == firstPicker {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
    }
```

Why this construction doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

To detect when a value is selected you must implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate`, also implement `didSelectRow` method of picker view. I'm assuming that you already populate your picker view data.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPicker: UIPickerView!
    var firstRaw = 1
        ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.firstPicker.delegate = self
        ...
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        if self.firstRaw == 0 {
            self.buttonOutlet.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.buttonOutlet.isEnabled = true
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did all of it. But still doesn’t work :(

Comment: What isn't work? The delegate methods? `isEnabled` button property?

Comment: isEnabled button property

Comment: see update, if it ins't works, try set on the hand in your `viewDidLoad`, to test. How you are populate your picker view? Please, let me see it.

Comment: @Alex I can't see where you are implementing `numberOfComponents`, `numberOfRowsInComponent` and `titleForRow` of your `UIPickerView`. If you don't implemented it, please implement, else show on your code.

Comment: yes I did. Just hard to add whole code above. `func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if pickerView == FirstPicker {
            return 1
        } else` , `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == firstPicker {
            return firstData.count
        }` , `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == firstPicker {`